# Transfer Files From Mac External Hard Drive To PC

Tags: macos, hardware

Our wedding videographer gave us our wedding video (all 200GB of it) on an external hard drive formatted for Mac.

My wife and I each have PCs and we have 2 external hard drives formatted for PCs. We have a Mac that's half dead, but we could use it for group sharing or something, but it doesn't have any internal space to store the large files.

Is there any way to get the files from this external hard drive onto one of our PCs?

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly a programming problem, but anyhow...

OSX uses HFS plus, not NTFS so a quick google search and you'll see that there are products available for what you want: -

http://www.pcadvisor.co.uk/how-to/windows/3369574/how-read-mac-os-hfs-drives-in-windows-for-free/